# etcd 404 page not found

Tags: postgresql, etcd, patroni

Ok, I am trying to understand postgres HA using etcd and patroni.  Here is my setup.

postgres node 1:10.0.10.225
psotgres node 2:10.0.10.24
etcd server:10.0.10.67
haproxy server:10.0.10.88

On the postgres server patroni is setup like this.

```
cope: postgres
namespace: /db/
name: pg-node1
restapi:
  listen: 10.0.10.225:8008
  connect_address: 10.0.10.225:8008
etcd:
  host: 10.0.10.67:2379
bootstrap:
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
    initdb:
        - encoding: UTF8
        - data-checksums
  pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator   127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator   10.0.10.225/0   md5
    - host replication replicator   10.0.10.24/0   md5
    - host all all   0.0.0.0/0   md5
  users:
    admin:
       password: admin
       options:
       - createrole
       - createdb
postgresql:
   listen: 10.0.10.225:5432
   connect_address: 10.0.10.225:5432
   data_dir:     /data/patroni
   pgpass:     /tmp/pgpass
   authentication:
    replication:
      username:   replicator
      password:     "mypassword"
    superuser:
      username:   suksh
      password:     "myotherpassword"
      parameters:
      unix_socket_directories:  '.'
tags:
   nofailover:   false
   noloadbalance:   false
   clonefrom:   false
   nosync:   false
```

On my etcd server I have this configuration:

```
# This is the configuration file for the etcd server.

# Human-readable name for this member.
name: 'default'

# Path to the data directory.
data-dir: /var/lib/etcd


# Path to the dedicated wal directory.
wal-dir:

# Number of committed transactions to trigger a snapshot to disk.
snapshot-count: 10000

# Time (in milliseconds) of a heartbeat interval.
heartbeat-interval: 100

# Time (in milliseconds) for an election to timeout.
election-timeout: 1000

# Raise alarms when backend size exceeds the given quota. 0 means use the
# default quota.
quota-backend-bytes: 0

# List of comma separated URLs to listen on for peer traffic.
listen-peer-urls: http://10.0.10.67:2380,http://127.0.0.1:7001

# List of comma separated URLs to listen on for client traffic.
listen-client-urls: http://127.0.0.1:2379, http://10.0.10.67:2379

# Maximum number of snapshot files to retain (0 is unlimited).
max-snapshots: 5

# Maximum number of wal files to retain (0 is unlimited).
max-wals: 5

# Comma-separated white list of origins for CORS (cross-origin resource sharing).
cors:

# List of this member's peer URLs to advertise to the rest of the cluster.
# The URLs needed to be a comma-separated list.
initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://10.0.10.67:2380

# List of this member's client URLs to advertise to the public.
# The URLs needed to be a comma-separated list.
advertise-client-urls: http://10.0.10.67:2379

# Discovery URL used to bootstrap the cluster.
discovery:

# Valid values include 'exit', 'proxy'
discovery-fallback: 'proxy'

# HTTP proxy to use for traffic to discovery service.
discovery-proxy:

# DNS domain used to bootstrap initial cluster.
discovery-srv:

# Comma separated string of initial cluster configuration for bootstrapping.
# Example: initial-cluster: "infra0=http://10.0.1.10:2380,infra1=http://10.0.1.11:2380,infra2=http://10.0.1.12:2380"
initial-cluster:

# Initial cluster token for the etcd cluster during bootstrap.
initial-cluster-token: 'etcd-cluster'

# Initial cluster state ('new' or 'existing').
initial-cluster-state: 'new'

# Reject reconfiguration requests that would cause quorum loss.
strict-reconfig-check: false

# Enable runtime profiling data via HTTP server
enable-pprof: true

# Valid values include 'on', 'readonly', 'off'
proxy: 'off'

# Time (in milliseconds) an endpoint will be held in a failed state.
proxy-failure-wait: 5000

# Time (in milliseconds) of the endpoints refresh interval.
proxy-refresh-interval: 30000

# Time (in milliseconds) for a dial to timeout.
proxy-dial-timeout: 1000

# Time (in milliseconds) for a write to timeout.
proxy-write-timeout: 5000

# Time (in milliseconds) for a read to timeout.
proxy-read-timeout: 0

client-transport-security:
  # Path to the client server TLS cert file.
  cert-file:

  # Path to the client server TLS key file.
  key-file:

  # Enable client cert authentication.
  client-cert-auth: false

  # Path to the client server TLS trusted CA cert file.
  trusted-ca-file:

  # Client TLS using generated certificates
  auto-tls: false

peer-transport-security:
  # Path to the peer server TLS cert file.
  cert-file:

  # Path to the peer server TLS key file.
  key-file:

  # Enable peer client cert authentication.
  client-cert-auth: false

  # Path to the peer server TLS trusted CA cert file.
  trusted-ca-file:

  # Peer TLS using generated certificates.
  auto-tls: false

# The validity period of the self-signed certificate, the unit is year.
self-signed-cert-validity: 1

# Enable debug-level logging for etcd.
log-level: debug

logger: zap

# Specify 'stdout' or 'stderr' to skip journald logging even when running under systemd.
log-outputs: [stderr]

# Force to create a new one member cluster.
force-new-cluster: false

auto-compaction-mode: periodic
auto-compaction-retention: "1"

# Limit etcd to a specific set of tls cipher suites
cipher-suites: [
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
]

# Limit etcd to specific TLS protocol versions
tls-min-version: 'TLS1.2'
tls-max-version: 'TLS1.3'
```

when I start the patroni service this.

```
Mar 01 20:37:57 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:37:57,811 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://10.0.10.67:2379/v2: EtcdException('Bad response : 404 page not found\n')
Mar 01 20:37:57 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:37:57,811 INFO: waiting on etcd
Mar 01 20:38:02 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:02,812 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://10.0.10.67:2379/v2: EtcdException('Bad response : 404 page not found\n')
Mar 01 20:38:02 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:02,813 INFO: waiting on etcd
Mar 01 20:38:07 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:07,814 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://10.0.10.67:2379/v2: EtcdException('Bad response : 404 page not found\n')
Mar 01 20:38:07 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:07,814 INFO: waiting on etcd
Mar 01 20:38:12 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:12,816 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://10.0.10.67:2379/v2: EtcdException('Bad response : 404 page not found\n')
Mar 01 20:38:12 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:12,816 INFO: waiting on etcd
Mar 01 20:38:17 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:17,817 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://10.0.10.67:2379/v2: EtcdException('Bad response : 404 page not found\n')
Mar 01 20:38:17 pg-node1 patroni[2005]: 2024-03-01 20:38:17,817 INFO: waiting on etcd
```

What have i setup wrong here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to add this in.  ```patroni --version
patroni 3.2.2```

Comment: ```etcd --version
etcd Version: 3.5.12
Git SHA: e7b3bb6cc
Go Version: go1.20.13
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64```